# What does module.exports = { Mongoose , models: { ... } } mean?

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose

I am learning Node/Mongo, and now I can understand the code like this,

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I have trouble understanding the following,

```
module.exports = { Mongoose, // var Mongoose = require('mongoose');
    models: {
        user: require('./schemas/user.js'),
        room: require('./schemas/room.js')
    }
};
```

I can see the author wants to export Mongoose and the models. But is the exported object a JSON object? Is the *Mongoose* in it a key or a value? Is JSON allowed a key without value or a value without a key? 
Or I am getting all wrong?

Comment: basically it's a new feature in es6, in whcih you can pass just variable & it'll worked as key & value with the same name as variable name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, just a clarification on terminology: **JSON** is a string and not an object hence it's abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. What you have is colloquially referred to as a **POJO** or **P**lain **O**ld **J**avascript **O**bject. They are different.

Second, lets break down the exports statement:

```
{ Mongoose, //...
```

This is ES6 (ES2015) syntax for [object initialization using shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). Basically, if a variable name (`var foo = 'hi'`) matches an object property name, then the initialization can simply be `{ foo }` which is the same as `{ foo: foo }`.

Regarding what is exported, it will be a POJO equivalent to:

```
{
    Mongoose: require('mongoose'),
    models: {
        user: require('./schemas/user.js'),
        room: require('./schemas/room.js')
    }
};
```

BONUS: Since Node maintains a cache of required modules, Mongoose uses this as a cacheing mechanism for all declared models and schemas. If in one file you import Mongoose and create a model, another module would be able to import Mongoose and have access to that model via Mongoose's cache.

```
// a.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const FooModel = new mongoose.model('Foo', {});

// b.js
const aMod = require('./a.js'); // Import here only to declare model.
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const FooModel = mongoose.model('Foo'); // Same model a.js
```

Comment: Some people are just really tough with their votes. I wouldn't sweat it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the author of that is using ES6 semantics.

In ES6, you can shorthand the following:

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const myObj = { Mongoose: Mongoose };
```

to:

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const myObj = { Mongoose };
```

Basically, it will interpret that as the same statement as above, providing the key is the same name as the named variable.

As an aside, exporting the mongoose object is unnecessary in the example you have or the one I have; the require cache will return the same instance of it every time in any event.